# Bake SVG into Android for PhoneGap Game

Tags: android, svg

I recently finished the first iteration of a game concept I was working on for mobile phones or browsers. My plan was to use PhoneGap and write it in JavaScript/HTML and port it everywhere. Because I wanted to be light on graphics and support any number of resolutions and orientations, I built this use SVG. I have been testing in Chrome and figured that the same SVG support would be on Android...

Well after doing some Googling, I see that the android devs specifically left out SVG rendering from the browser... I assume this means that once I convert my app into PhoneGap format, it won't run on Android. Is there any way to bake-in SVG rendering with a PhoneGap plugin or something, or am I SOL?

I [saw that Honeycomb](http://googlesystem.blogspot.com/2011/02/android-honeycombs-browser-supports-svg.html) has support for SVG, does anyone know if they plan on backporting this to 2.2, 2.3, etc? It seems to be a huge oversight that if you want to support multiple resolutions and screens you wouldn't incorporate a technology than can dynamically create graphics.

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned in your question, support for SVG was compiled into the Webkit browser for Android 3.0. I just tried the Android 3.1 emulator, and it is working there as well:

[image]

So it appears as though, for future releases, we can probably count on SVG support being included in the Webkit browser.

I am not aware of any work being done to bring SVG to the webkit browser on earlier versions of Android.

Answer (score 0):

You *might* be able to use [canvg](https://code.google.com/p/canvg/) which uses javascript to interpret SVG and draw it on the canvas. I expect performance will be too slow for a game, though (I've not tried it myself yet)